# Weird line following my cursor when sculpting

Tags: interface, sculpting

Why do I have this line following my cursor?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's smooth stroke, it is intended to smooth out mouse/pen movement, you might have heard of it under a different name: lazy mouse.

Imagine it as tough your cursor is pulling the actual brush.

To disable go into sculpt mode -> tools -> stroke -> disable smooth stroke.

Answer (score 7):

In Blender 2.82+ it´s under *Stroke > Stabilize Stroke*. You need to disable the option in the red circle.

[image: stroke blender 2.82a]

[Link to the docs :](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/stroke.html#stabilize-stroke)

> Stabilize Stroke makes the stroke lag behind the cursor and applies a
> smoothed curve to the path of the cursor. This can be enabled
> temporary by holding Shift-S while painting or permanently by clicking
> the checkbox found in the header.
>
> Radius
>
> ```
> Sets the minimum distance from the last point before stroke continues.
> ```
>
> Factor
>
> ```
> Sets the amount of smoothing.
> ```