# Weight Paint brush doesn't change mesh colors; draws cyan line instead

Tags: weight-painting

What does that thin bluish-cyan line I boxed mean, and how do I get rid of it? I'm trying to weight-paint this thumb region, and instead of turning any vertex click-dragged over into various colors based on my weight, it draws this weird line and only *maybe* weights a vertex passed over. Restart did not resolve the issue. The weights you see here were had by assigning variable weights to the relevant VGs manually.

Oddly enough, the issue seems to only happen on the Draw brush (Add behaved as expected). I *could* use the other brushes, but I prefer the precision of Draw.

EDIT: My WP and Sculpt modes seem to have different "stabilize stroke" options, and WP's was enabled, not Sculpt's (the linked question was Sculpt only). Not sure how I did that when I never expand the Stroke option--is there a hotkey I accidentally pressed?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird line following my cursor when sculpting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82899/weird-line-following-my-cursor-when-sculpting)

Comment: No--I never use Sculpt mode, and the Stabilize Stroke option was already disabled.

Comment: The brushes in sculpt and vertex weight paint modes work the same way. I'm really curious about what would be causing this if not stabilize stroke because the screenshot and your description both point to the stabilize behaviour

Comment: just a little hint: One red arrow to the line would be much better to see than your "20 degree...."-description.....

Comment: Image replaced. Seems it's the day for my Blender to glitch out...

Comment: @Gorgious Wait, you were right! The thing you linked pointed to Sculpt mode only, but there's an identical setting in WP mode that Idk how I turned on. It seems separate from the Sculpt version of the setting, because I left WP's on and Sculpt's was still off. (So... how did I turn it on in the first place??)